# each time one event

Tags: xaml

each time one is clicked how can I do that

Comment: Hi Marko, glad to see your first question here. This is not a code writing service though, I would recommend asked questions to help you refactor your code.  What is preventing you from refactoring it to not use GoTo statements? What have you tried?

Comment: How about Continue For

Comment: VB for sure has arrays, does it. As soon as you write code like var1, var2, var3, ... to then manually process all these variables the same way ... you should learn about arrays, and loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something you could try. I'm not using the `IsNullOrEmpty` test as you are already resetting them beforehand so not needed.

Putting the `Buttons` in a small array would simplify things.

You could try this: ( tested with `Option Strict On`)

```
Private Sub ButtonShuffle_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonShuffle.Click

    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim numberList As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(Function(i) rnd.Next).ToList

    Dim buttons As Button() = {Button0, Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8, Button9}
    Dim buttonCurrent As Integer = 0

    For Each num As Integer In numberList
        buttons(buttonCurrent).Content = num.ToString
        buttonCurrent += 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Very clean and clever with the randomly ordered list.

Comment: @Marko Markowitz I added another answer as per request.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your `Button0` to `Button9` `Click` events and replace them with this:

```
Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button0.Click, Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click
    Shuffle()
End Sub
```